# ASP.NET failing to call a dll

Tags: asp.net, .net, dll, iis-7, vb6

My question may have already been asked but any of the answers match my case.

I need to do a website (ASP.NET MVC 4) with some features of a software. I have finished to developed my website and wanted to test it in a test environment (Windows server 2008 - 64bits). 
It works perfectly fine with my dev computer(windows 7 - 64bits). But after I deployed it on IIS, one of my features doesn't work.

This feature is a bit particular. It need a 32 bits COM written in VB6 (this dll can't be change) that call an other dll. When I test the website deployed on IIS, the first ddl is called fine but the 2nd seemed to be not called at all. 
This dll are in the installed file of the software. I have the same version of on both computer.

I authorize my app pool to use 32bits application. I tried to give some access to my dll (the COM and interop) like IUSR, IIS_IUSRS. But nothing seems to work. 
I have checked both of my dll are registered properly. 
I'm a bit lost. Can someone help me ?

PS: Sorry for my English, I can speak but I'm really weak with syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestion here:

You need to figure out which managed dll, native dll and lib files are referenced by your application (directly or indirectly).

For managed dll, make sure they are in the web's bin folder.

For native dll and .lib files, check out whether those .dll and .lib files are in the PATH. If not, you can either copy them to there; or, you can put them into a folder and add that folder into the PATH. Then restart VS and IIS (command "iisreset") to make sure the setting is picked up.

By the way, putting all of the files in the web's bin folder won't help. The reason is CLR copies the files into a temporary folder under framework directory and run the web there, but CLR only copies away managed dll (not the native ones), so you still get "module not found" error.

I have reproduced this error using the following sample solution

1. Web1 references a managed c++ project say "MCpp1.dll". The project further references two unmanaged c++ projects with the output say "Lib1.lib" and "Lib2.lib"
2. If I copy all of those files into web's bin folder, I get the exception of "module not found error".
3. I create a folder say "C:\Lib" and copy "Lib1.lib" and "Lib2.lib" into it and add this folder into PATH. I restart VS, and also run "IISReset" since I have a IIS web
4. Open VS and request a page and it works now

I have also contacted the CLR/Fusion team for suggestion of how to get the related module name when this exception happens, which should be very helpful to make diagnosis.

Hope this helps ,

GODFATHER

Comment: I'm still not very familiar with that (I'm doing my first ASP.NET website). But why does it work on my dev machine and not on my testing machine? On my dev machine, I didn't need to add anything in the PATH.

Comment: I have another question. You talk about native and managed dll. I don't know that so I did some digging but I'm not sure if I understand right. Can you explain me more in details the difference between the two? thanks